# Google ColaboratoryにGoogle Chromeの最新版とChromeDriverの最新版がインストールできないです。

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, google-colaboratory, chromedriver

Google Colaboratory上でSeleniumを動かしたいので、

- Google Chromeの最新版
- ChromeDriverの最新版

をそれぞれインストールしたいです。
しかし、実行してもエラーが出現します。

#### 前提条件

- 開発環境はGoogle Colaboratory
- Seleniumでスクレイピングをしたい。

#### 期待値

- Google Chromeの最新版とChromeDriverの最新版のインストールを成功させる。
- 上記二つのバージョンを一致させる。

#### 再現手順

###### インストール時のコマンド

```
%%shell

sudo apt -y update && sudo apt -y upgrade
sudo apt install -y wget curl unzip

# Google Chromeの依存関係をインストール
sudo apt install libu2f-udev libvulkan1

# ChromeをDL&インストール
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

# ChromeDriverをDL&インストール
wget -N https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/99.0.4844.84/chromedriver_linux64.zipp -P /tmp/
unzip -o /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /tmp/
chmod +x /tmp/chromedriver
mv /tmp/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

###### 実行結果

```
前略

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
wget is already the newest version (1.21.2-2ubuntu1).
curl is already the newest version (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.13).
unzip is already the newest version (6.0-26ubuntu3.1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libu2f-udev but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libvulkan1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libu2f-udev : Depends: udev (>= 244) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
--2023-09-24 13:29:01--  https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 142.250.99.136, 142.250.99.93, 142.250.99.190, ...
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|142.250.99.136|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 103481376 (99M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb.2’

中略

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libu2f-udev; however:
  Package libu2f-udev is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libvulkan1; however:
  Package libvulkan1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
--2023-09-24 13:29:15--  https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/99.0.4844.84/chromedriver_linux64.zipp
Resolving chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com (chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com)... 74.125.135.207, 74.125.195.207, 172.253.117.207, ...
Connecting to chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com (chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com)|74.125.135.207|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2023-09-24 13:29:15 ERROR 404: Not Found.

中略

unzip:  cannot find or open /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip, /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip.zip or /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip.ZIP.
chmod: cannot access '/tmp/chromedriver': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '/tmp/chromedriver': No such file or directory

中略

CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)

中略

CalledProcessError: Command '
実行したコマンド
' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

#### マルチポスト

[teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/kjagcay4hi0m1c)にも同じ質問を投稿しています。

Comment: いくつか記事が見つかりますが、みな微妙に違っていますね。例えばこんなもののどれかが参考になるかも。[Colaboratory & Seleniumを使った自動化ツールが定期的に動かなくなるので動くようにする](https://zenn.dev/cbcloud_blog/articles/4f2898abb4c396), [Google ColaboratoryでseleniumとChrome Driverをインストールする](https://qiita.com/76r6qo698/items/cfea95c6b77ddaae518d), [Google ColaboratoryでSeleniumを使うための設定](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/google-colaboratory-use-selenium/)

Comment: @kunif 他の人も動かすのに苦労してるんですね.,..。
やっぱり、ローカルに環境構築した方が無難でしょうか？

Comment: 調査や対処に時間を取られて本当にしたいことが何も出来ないよりは、ローカルな環境でサッサと始めた方が良いのでは？

Comment: @kunif わかりました。ローカルな環境でも試してみます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下で、Google Colaboratory上で、動作しました。
いかがでしょうか？

◇インストール方法

```
# Seleniumのインストール

!wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
!dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
!rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
!apt install -y chromium-chromedriver

!pip3 install --upgrade selenium
!pip3 install --upgrade webdriver-manager
```

◇実行

```
# Seleniumの実行

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

service = ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install())
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--lang=ja-JP')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get('https://google.com')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# 出力
element_list = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, soup.text.split(' '))
for element in element_list:
    print(element)
```

Comment: chromium-chromedriverとchromedriverの違いが知りたいです。